# Key Signature Reasoning

Tags: key

I'm looking through a piece of music that has two flats in the key signature. It feels like it's in D minor (the last chord), and the verse alternates between E♭9 and Dm6.

A couple of things - why would the arranger use that key signature? Would the E♭9 be a tritone substitute for what could easily be A7? Could it actually be in a mode instead?

It's Dizzie Gillespie's Night in Tunisia. I've played it with one flat, which somehow makes more sense than 2.

Comment: Duuude!   please post the name & composer, if not an image of the chart!

Comment: The clue was enough for jazzers! A Night in Tunisia. Dizzy.

Comment: We're supposed to guess what the music is, why?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - no, I didn't want to fall foul of the rule 'what key is this in?' and lose the question. Eb9 and Dm don't feature in many (any?) keys, so the question was based on that. Lots here will have played it many times.

Comment: Possibly the key signature hints at Phrygian, the `E` flat being added to `D` minor. Given the particular song it sort of announces "exotic"

Comment: For a site that often votes to close stuff for being too vague or broad, to not include all the info and leaving hard to find clues for the users to find seems strange to me. Can you please edit the question to include more info so maybe it is helpful to others in the future?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - D Phrygian came to mind - that would prompt a key sig. of 2 flats.

Comment: What is the source of the chart? When I look it up, it appears the Real Book uses one flat.

Comment: I'm still stuck on the Dm6 in a key with two flats, there'd have to be an accidental natural sign in every measure!

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - yes, I checked that too. One flat.

Comment: This piece is clearly D minor. The Eb7 is in my opinion a borrowed chord (or like an extended chromatic approach to D). But you can also  try to press free jazz in a schema of classical chord progression, or Prokofiev or Bartok. (I'd like to poste some pieces of Bartok analysed  with Jazz harmony.) Btw. *A NIGHT IN TUNISIA*  has got an analysis in wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Night_in_Tunisia

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli, yes, borrowed. But from where? If borrowed from Phrygian, a Phrygian key signature just takes us there directly.

Comment: @dissemin8or, FWIW, the Real Book chart I found uses neither the Eb in the signature nor the 6 on Dm. It seems there is some confusion related to this specific chart ...that we can't see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without judging whether it appropriate, I think the reason someone might use two flats in the key signature is the `Eb7` chord of the vamp and the `E` flat at the end of the first part of the melody...

[image]

...could be considered to come from the Phrygian mode rather than tritone substitution/altered dominant harmony.

If a tritone substitute is considered clearly identifiable only when part of a descending fifth progression, then it seems reasonable to say the `Eb7` chord here is *not* a tritone substitution, but a chord rooted on the lowered second degree of Phrygian.

In other words `iim7b5 bII7 i` would be a clear case of tritone substitution, `bII` subs for `V`, because it substitutes in a progression of three roots by descending fifth. But just alternating `bII7 i bII7 i` is not the clear substitution within a descending fifths progression pattern.

So, if someone took that view - the `Eb7` is not a tritone substitution - the chord is diatonic to Phrygian (at least the base triad), the Phrygian key signature reinforces that idea.

When the tune gets to using a dominant rooted on `A` at end the phrase, and it has a proper leading tone, that doesn't *contradict* Phrygian, not in the classical sense, so that seems like additional support for Phrygian.

Either way it doesn't change what's happening tonally. It's a little like when Baroque scores would use *zero* flats for `D` minor. The sharps and flats in the score make the final determination of tonality.

Answer (score 1):

I think the E♭9 is the "foreign" chord here. So i think the piece (hard without having seen the whole piece) is correctly in D minor, with the E♭9 possible a tritone substitute.

I think you were on the right track, but if you can share the whole piece, then i can get it right 100%.

Comment: D minor has one flat.  So that's not the answer

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - we know that!! What I want to know is some reason why the arranger thought 2flats more appropriate. To me, it's in Dm, (with 1 flat), so don't dv this answer!

Comment: @Tim I didn't DV

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - answer  - or question?

Comment: @Tim  either so far as I recall